# Animating a rifle

Tags: animation, rigging, armature, bones

I've made an assault rifle and rigged it, both for animation and for use in Unreal Engine 4. I've tried before to make such animations, by animating both the weapon and then the hands, however both separately, the rifle first then syncing the hands with it. However the animation didn't turn out as well as I'd hoped.
Is there a way for the gun or hand to follow the other? If I do something like parent the gun to hand, how would I do a reload animation where a hand may have to leave its place?
Thanks